# the script freezes on the latest data in real time (repainting) and shows the desired value only when the browser page is refreshed

Tags: pine-script, indicator

```
study("Stepper",overlay=true)
//version.3
long_timeframe = input(title="Long timeframe", type=resolution, defval="1440")
ha_symbol = heikinashi(tickerid)
long_ha_close = security(ha_symbol, long_timeframe, close)
long_step = ema(long_ha_close,1)
plot(long_step,title="LongStep",color=white,linewidth=2,style=line)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With this code you can choose between a repainting and non-repainting signal. Note that your ema length being 1, you could just as well use `close` in the `long_step` definition:

```
//@version=3
study("Stepper",overlay=true)

long_timeframe = input(title="Long timeframe", type=resolution, defval="1440")
repaint = input(false, "Repainting signal?")

ha_symbol = heikinashi(tickerid)
long_step = ema(close, 1)
long_ha_close1 = security(ha_symbol, long_timeframe, long_step[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
long_ha_close2 = security(ha_symbol, long_timeframe, long_step)
long_ha_close = repaint ? long_ha_close2 : long_ha_close1

plot(long_ha_close,title="LongStep",color=blue,linewidth=2,style=line)
```

For more info on the subject:

https://www.tradingview.com/script/cyPWY96u-How-to-avoid-repainting-when-using-security-PineCoders-FAQ/
https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Indicator_repainting.html

Comment: the deepest bow and respect to you, smart great man! I have not really figured it out yet and will delve into your amendment (I am new and not experienced).
But for now, there is one point that I would like to ask you to comment on - your wonderful code has an offset of 30 forward compared to my original code. Why is this happening and what can be done? insert the line  "step shift?"

Comment: The best way to understand what's going on is to load our [script](https://www.tradingview.com/script/cyPWY96u-How-to-avoid-repainting-when-using-security-PineCoders-FAQ/) on a chart and analyze the plots. Basically, there's no way around the fact that if you want to avoid repainting you have to use a past value that is locked in. What the combo of using the `[1]` offset and `lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on` does is fetch the last locked value of the previous bar, which entails that the value is always late, but it's the *most recent late* value of the 1D TF, if you will )

Comment: thank you. I need a little time to digest the information and give an adequate comment ... your article with the script is very interesting, I need to stop and study this